# jQuery calculator(json requests)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have code of a calculator. It takes data from the PHP array (using json). Then it searchs by input's id and shows the price. On click I add new row of inputs. But this new row doesn't show me real price. What should I do to make it work?

Site with calculator: http://mktester4.tk/%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B/ push "подсчитать цену"
Code of a calculator:

```
     $(".click").hide();
     $(".zone-item input:checkbox").click(function () {
         var zoneItem = $(this).closest(".zone-item");
         zoneItem.toggleClass("activated");
         zoneItem.children(".js-form-controls").slideToggle("fast");
         $(".click").show();

    if (zoneItem.hasClass("activated")) {
        var zoneItemId = $(this).closest(".zone-item").attr("id");
        $("#" + zoneItemId + " .age-selector").change(function () {
        var ageItem = $("option:selected", this).attr("value");
        $("#" + zoneItemId + " .age-selector-value").each(function(){
            $(this).html(ageItem);
        });
    });
    $("#" + zoneItemId + " .time-selector").change(function () {
        var timeItem = $("option:selected", this).attr("value");
        $("#" + zoneItemId + " .time-selector-value").each(function(){
            $(this).html(timeItem);
        });
    });
    $("#" + zoneItemId + " .number-selector").change(function () {
        var peopleCount = $(this).attr("value");
        $("#" + zoneItemId + " .people-selector-value").each(function(){
            $(this).html(peopleCount);
        });
    });
    //createNewRow
    $(this).closest(".zone-item").delegate( ".click", "click",     
        function() {
          var additionalInputs = 
        $("#" + zoneItemId + " .js-form-controls")
        .html();

    $(this).closest(".zone-item")
    .after( "<div class='js-form-controls'>"+ 
        additionalInputs +"</div>" );
    });


    $("#" + zoneItemId + " .form-control").change(function() {
        $("span.age-selector-value, span.time-selector-value, span.price-for-zone")
    .css("display", "none");
    var finalAge = $("#" + zoneItemId + " .age-selector-value") .html();
    var finalTime = $("#" + zoneItemId + " .time-selector-value").html();
    var finalPeopleCount = 
        $("#" + zoneItemId + " .people-selector-value").html();
    var zonePrice= $("#" + zoneItemId + " .price-for-zone");

    zonePrice.html(window.prices[zoneItemId][finalTime][finalAge]);

    var sum=0;
    var multipliedPrice = 
        $("#" + zoneItemId + " .price-for-zone")
        .html() * finalPeopleCount;
        $("#" + zoneItemId + " .multiplied-price-for-zone")
        .html(multipliedPrice);

        $(".multiplied-price-for-zone").each(function(){
            sum += Number($(this).html());
        });
        $(".js-final-price").html(sum);
        });
      }

 else {
    var zoneItemId = $(this).closest(".zone-item").attr("id");
    var finalPeopleCount = $(".people-selector-value").html();
    $("#" + zoneItemId + " .price-for-zone").html(0);
    $("#" + zoneItemId + " .people-selector-value").html(1);
    $("#" + zoneItemId + " .number-selector").val(1);
    $("#" + zoneItemId + " select").val('default');
    var sum=0;
    $(".price-for-zone").each(function(){
        sum += Number($(this).html()*finalPeopleCount);
    });
    $(".js-final-price").html(sum);
    }
    });
```